# How to check the current text from a PyGTK Statusbar?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, statusbar

I'm writing unit tests for my PyGTK2 GUI and at various points I need to check the text that is shown in a `gtk.Statusbar`. The class defines a `pop()` function but it does not return anything. How can I non-destructively get the text is currently displayed?

Comment: You control which messages go on to the StatusBar stack, so you should keep track of which one is being displayed. pop method removes a message if you kept it's id. The signals [text-popped](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkstatusbar.html#signal-gtkstatusbar--text-popped) and [text-pushed](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkstatusbar.html#signal-gtkstatusbar--text-pushed) give you the text while pushing/popping but you are actually adding/removing it. GtkStatusBar does not expose the label which contains the text being shown so you must rethink your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())

        bigbtn = Gtk.Button("Show elements")
        bigbtn.connect("clicked", self.on_bigbtn_clicked)

        self.stat = Gtk.Statusbar()
        for id, lbl in enumerate(["One", "Two", "Three"]):
            self.stat.push(id, lbl)

        vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        vbox.pack_start(bigbtn, True, True, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(self.stat, False, False, 0)

        self.add(vbox)
        self.show_all()

    def on_bigbtn_clicked(self, btn):
        for el in self.stat.get_message_area():
            print(el.get_text())

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Clicking on the top button will print the contents of the current message. The trick is to first access the `message_area` of the status bar, which is of type `Gtk.Box`. You can then access the element in the box (which is of type `Gtk.Label` - so, a `get_text()` gets you the text.

This is `Gtk` through Introspection, but it *is* Python 2. You should be able to modify this code to `pygtk` easily - probably just change the import and `Gtk` to `gtk`.

Comment: Works great, and since this is test code I don't mind introspection at all